# Bash - substituting parameter in parent match (SED/AWK)

Tags: bash, solaris, yaml

I'm working on a small script to take some variables, packageName, newVersion.  I've googled and tried an awful lot and it brings me to asking.

The script executes as: updatePackage.sh -p weblogic-pkg-1 -v 2.0.1-B3

This reads yaml:

```
## Weblogic Deployment
   'weblogic-pkg-1':
     ensure:            'present'
     deploymenttype:    'AppDeployment'
     versionidentifier: '2.0.0-B2'
     timeout:           60
     stagingmode:       "nostage"
     remote:            "1"
     upload:            "1"
     target:
       - "%{hiera('package_clustername')}"
     targettype:
       - 'Cluster'
     localpath:         '/opt/releases/staging/applications/weblogic-pkg-1/weblogic-pkg-1-2.0.0-B2.war'
```

I am trying to get the script to change the version number once it has matched the package, so the desired output is:

```
## Weblogic Deployment
   'weblogic-pkg-1':
     ensure:            'present'
     deploymenttype:    'AppDeployment'
     versionidentifier: '2.0.1-B3'
     timeout:           60
     stagingmode:       "nostage"
     remote:            "1"
     upload:            "1"
     target:
       - "%{hiera('package_clustername')}"
     targettype:
       - 'Cluster'
     localpath:         '/opt/releases/staging/applications/weblogic-pkg-1/weblogic-pkg-1-2.0.1-B3.war'
```

The YAML file has about 50 packages so I cannot just sed /version/newVersion sadly.  The system is also pretty locked down so adding a yaml parser to the OS might be tricky.

Any tips?

Thanks

Dave

Comment: Maybe the question is obvious for you, but you should add more details. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I take what you posted to be the original file, if so then please post the file as you would like it to be modified by `sed` or `awk`. Also post the commands you've been using so others may suggest how to fix them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I've updated the original question so that it is hopefully a little more understandable :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed it with perl.
I hope this helps someone else:

```
#perl -000 -n -i -e "s/versionidentifier: '2.0.0-B1'/versionidentifier: '2.0.0-B3'/m if /\'weblogic-pkg-1\':/; print;" /opt/releases/staging/hiera/dev/deployments/node.corp.yaml
```

For the directory update, change the delimiter to an @:

```
perl -000 -n -i -e "s@localpath:         '/opt/releases/staging/applications/weblogic-pkg-1/weblogic-pkg-1-2.0.0-B1.war''@localpath:         '/opt/releases/staging/applications/weblogic-pkg-1/weblogic-pkg-1-2.0.1-B2.war'@m if /\'vet-common-status-service\':/; print;" /opt/releases/staging/hiera/dev/deployments/node.corp.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you got the hang of it with `perl`. That's what I would have suggested:

```
perl -lape "if (/'weblogic-pkg-1':/../localpath:/ and /versionidentifier|localpath:/) {\$a = \$1 if /\s+versionidentifier: '(.+)'/;s/\$a/2.0.1-B3/}" input.txt
```

If you want to wrap it in a Bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while getopts ":p:v:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    p) p="$OPTARG"
    ;;
    v) v="$OPTARG"
    ;;
    \?) echo "Invalid option -$OPTARG" >&2
    ;;
  esac
done

perl -lape "if (/'$p':/../localpath:/ and /versionidentifier|localpath:/) {\$a = \$1 if /\s+versionidentifier: '(.+)'/;s/\$a/$v/}" input.txt
```

**Note:** I did not include the `-i` switch because it is dangerous: you should first experiment and tweak the script to your needs, and only then substitute `perl -i -lane` instead of `perl -lane`.